# Updating a column from another table where datetime has multiple values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables and I have to fill the Code column from `table1` with the values from code in `table2`. The Date column is of type `datetime` with the date column from `table1` not having values for time while the date from `table2` does have the time.

Table1:

```
    Code  Date 
    NULL  2018-5-6 00:00:00
    NULL  2018-5-6 00:00:00
    NULL  2018-5-6 00:00:00
    NULL  2018-5-6 00:00:00
    NULL  2017-7-4 00:00:00
    NULL  2016-1-3 00:00:00
```

And Table2:

```
    Code  Date 
    F444  2018-5-6 01:30:00
    T777  2018-5-6 07:00:00
    R545  2017-7-4 00:00:00
    D432  2016-1-3 00:00:00
```

When I try to join the tables and update the Code from table1 I can only get one date from table2 to fill in the code.

Result:

```
Code  Date 
F444  2018-5-6 00:00:00
F444  2018-5-6 00:00:00
F444  2018-5-6 00:00:00
F444  2018-5-6 00:00:00
R545  2017-7-4 00:00:00
D432  2016-1-3 00:00:00
```

How could I update the code column to show all of the codes if one date has multiple times in the other table?

Intended Result:

```
   Code  Date 
F444  2018-5-6 00:00:00
F444  2018-5-6 00:00:00
T777  2018-5-6 00:00:00
T777  2018-5-6 00:00:00
R545  2017-7-4 00:00:00
D432  2016-1-3 00:00:00
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Updating-- same ntile concept but with getting records in to #temp for avoid performance problem while updating.

**Logic-Follows**

drop table #temp
select b.code,a.date ,ntile(2) over (partition by a.date order by a.date) as t1 into #temp from ( select *,ntile(2) over (partition by date order by date) as tt from t1 )a left join (select *,rank() over (partition by convert(date,date) order by date) as ttr from t2 )b on convert(date,a.[date])=convert(date,b.[date]) and a.tt=b.ttr

update a
set code=b.code
from (select *,ntile(2) over (partition by date order by date) as t1 from t1) a 
inner join  #temp b on (a.date=b.date and a.t1=b.t1)

Answer (score 1):

This is rather tricky.  You need to enumerate the matching values in the two tables and then use that information for the update.

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
update t
    set code = t2.code
    from toupdate t join
         (select t2.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as seqnum,
                 count(*) over (partition by date) as cnt
          from table2 t2
         ) t2
         on t.date = t2.date and
            t1.seqnum % t2.cnt = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: I tried using this but the code column from table1 is still NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

We can equally distribute the value using ntile function in sql.

select b.code,a.date from (
select *,ntile(2) over (partition by date order by date) as tt  from t1 )a
left join 
(select *,rank() over (partition by convert(date,date) order by date) as ttr  from t2
)b on convert(date,a.[date])=convert(date,b.[date]) and  a.tt=b.ttr

Comment: While this works using SELECT how would this work if I want to update the values for the Code column table1?